Database.QueryLocator mocking during unit test
Let's say we have
public DataBase.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    if(this.sources.size() == 0) return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id FROM Account WHERE id = null');
    Id tempoId = this.sources[this.current]; 
    String statement = String.format('{0} Parent.Profile.Id = :tempoId', 
        new string[]{ MigrationToolsHelper.getObjectPermisionsStatement(true)});
    // if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
    //     statement = 
    // }
    return Database.getQueryLocator(statement);
}

full statement is
SELECT Id, SobjectType,Parent.Profile.Id, ParentId, PermissionsRead,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsCreate,PermissionsDelete FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE  Parent.Profile.Id = :tempoId

What can i do to return List<ObjectPermissions> instead of DataBase.getQueryLocator()?

It's not entirely clear why you're trying to mock this. Also, you can get an iterator from a query locator, iterate through it, and build a List of records that way.

how can i provide this list to execute method?

...by providing it in your call to execute()? It is just a method after all, so you call it and provide parameters to it just like you would when calling any other method. Including more details and showing us exactly what you're trying to do would be helpful (and faster than trying to suss out details bit by bit in the comments).

i'm a liitle bit confused. start method has type of Database.Querylocator. How it's possible to provide List?

This seems like an X-Y problem to me. There should be no need to mock things here.
Assuming that you're simply trying to write a unit test for a batch class, you should generally be calling the start(), execute(), and finish() methods manually (instead of doing Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());). The goal, after all, is to stress the logic that you've written, not to test the implementation details behind how Salesforce ends up calling those methods.
For the following example batch class
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        for(Account acct : (List<Account>)scope) {
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
    }
}

You could test it like so
@isTest
private without sharing class MyBatchTest {
    // The usual test data setup (since test data is isolated from "real" data)
    @SetupTest
    private static makeData() {
        insert new Account(Name = 'TestAcc - MyBatchTest');
    }

    @isTest
    static void callStart_returnsRecords() {
        // You can call .start() just like any other method
        // If you're not using the batchable context (and most people don't), then it's
        //   fine to pass null in for that parameter
        Database.QueryLocator locator = new MyBatch().start(null);

        // Locators can give us an iterator, which is what we need to be able to extract
        //   records from it.
        Iterator resultIterator = locator.iterator();

        List<Account> results = new List<Account>();
        while(resultIterator.hasNext()) {
            results.add((Account)resultIterator.next());
        }

        Assert.isFalse(results.isEmpty(), 'Should have gotten at least one Account');
    }

    @isTest
    static void callExecute_doesNotCroak() {
        MyBatch systemUnderTest = new MyBatch();

        // While you could call .start(), it's generally better to have tests execute
        //   as little of the code in the SUT (System Under Test), triggers, etc...
        //   as possible
        List<Account> testData = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];

        // Likewise, execute() is just another method that can be called
        // All you need to do is pass in what the method asks for
        Test.startTest();
        systemUnderTest.execute(null, testData);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest
    static void callFinish() {
        new MyBatch().finish(null);
    }
}

